Create a Data Stream via Apex Test
Is it possible to create a Data Stream via Apex within a Test class?
My Apex Controller queries for Data Streams (and other Data Cloud Metadata Types) and creates metadata records for each result. This all works fine, but I'm unsure how to test this.
In my test class, I tried to do:
DataStream ds = new DataStream();
ds.Name = 'Test';
ds.RefreshMode = 'FULL_REFRESH';
ds.RefreshFrequency = 'NONE';
insert ds;

test.startTest();
processMetadataForDCAlerts.newSetup(formInputs);
test.stopTest();

The code I'm trying to test:
public static Id newSetup(String formInputs) {     
    List<SObject> metadataToDeploy = new List<SObject>();
    Map<String, Object> formValues = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(formInputs);
    String typesToDeploy = String.valueOf(formValues.get('typesToDeploy'));
    
    //Deploy Data Stream if the option is seleted and there are any records to deploy.
    if(typesToDeploy.contains('DataStream')) {
      for(DataStream ds : [SELECT Id, Name FROM DataStream]) {
         metadataToDeploy.add(ds);
      }
    }
}

This results in a Internal Salesforce Error: 1908774572-71211 (-1111796172) (-1111796172). The same applies if I try to do this via a flow that I just run in debug mode. So I assume it is buggy and not possible to do this? Is there a workaround when I can't guarantee the org will have any metadata setup at all.
